# How to installed Debian 8.8 uEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, debian, debian-installer

I have a machine with uEFI firmware.  Windows 10 is installed using uEFI method.  Debian 8.8 Jessie seems to report that it is installing with BIOS method and not uEFI, because during grub bootloader installation Debian asks to choose location of MBR record.

Answer (score 0):

You are using one of Debian 8.8 Live DVDs with pre-configured desktop like Gnome or KDE.

Try using standard Debian installation DVD.  It is configured to run legacy BIOS mode (uses MBR) and new uEFI installation mode.

When this CD boots it has a message that directly states it is a uEFI installer.   That message is on the very 1st menu that gives you a choice of graphical vs. non-graphical installation.

The Live DVDs don't state that they don't support uEFI and can waste you a lot of time.